# mysql database backup running on linux

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, database-backups, mysql-backup

I have a Mysql database running on amazon-ec2. I doubt if I can use workbench or something. In that case, how can I safely backup my database.

I want something portable, like some command I hit and I get a file or zip that I can carry anywhere with easy.

I know about mysqldump. But it gives me set of INSERT/CREATE queries. 
Can I create backup as a database object?

Comment: As I have mentioned in question details, I know about mysqldump. But I don't like the idea of storing everything in form of queries. Any other solution?

Comment: Take it from someone who's been working on backup and snapshot software for some time: dumps are the way, unless your DB is so huuge, that dumps become problematic. All other solutions are far harder to implement, and break far more easily.

Comment: *"But I don't like the idea of storing everything in form of queries."*  This question portrays profoundly misdirected thinking or a substantial misunderstanding of what `mysqldump` is designed to do -- create a logical backup that can be used to *reconstruct* a database to an identical state from a human readable source file with no black box behavior, no invisible moving parts whatsoever, and no opportunity for preserving hidden defects. It is the *de facto* **standard tool** and quite simply the most foolproof and best guard against a backup that you can't restore and can't figure out why.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I understand and respect what you said. But I don't want a text file that anyone can read/change if by change one gets access to it. So what you said is correct but it is purely my requirement that leads me to this question. Sorry for troubles.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  Not wanting the backup file to be usable by an unauthorized person seems to be a perfectly reasonable requirement, but it is not, *prima facie*, a valid reason to object to using to `mysqldump` as a tool.  The data files generated by other tools, like xtrabackup, are not *human*-readable, but this is a false sense of security -- it is still relatively trivial for a determined bad actor to extract your data if in possession of the file.  It is important to communicate your *actual* underlying requirements.